# Is it possible to constrain the outcome of lsqnonlin in matlab to only real solutions?

Tags: matlab, data-fitting

I would like to fit a transfer function of a PD-controller + time-delay to frequency response data ( so these are complex numbers) in matlab. The fit function is: (P+D*iw)* exp(tau*iw) I used least-squares minimization with the Matlab function lsqnonlin and set the start and boundary values, to obtain the parameters P, D and tau. These values should be real numbers, however I obtain complex numbers, because my function and data are complex as well. Is there a way to constrain the solution to only real numbers?

Comment: are you using some symbolic variable ? if yes you can add a constraint on your variable: `syms yourvariable real`. So matlab understand that the answer need to be real (if a real answer exist)

Comment: Try to read https://it.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fit-model-to-complex-data.html. I would suggest you to keep your optimization variables real, and then generate a complex function that will fit your data.